# How to apply the principle of dependency inversion in the provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, solid

I want my project to follow the SOLID principles, and for that I want to know if the coupling that is always seen between the UI and the providers in various tutorials is something that violates the principle of dependency inversion or not.

I remember the definition at the beginning:

> A. High level classes should not depend on low level classes. Both
> should depend on abstractions.
>
> B. Abstractions should not depend on details. The details should
> depend on the abstractions.

By this I mean this application that you see a lot in tutorials:

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  //...
}

class UIClass extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     MyProvider myProvider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);
     //...
  }
}
```

As can be seen, the UI class directly instantiates the provider class and not an interface, generating coupling between these two classes.

I understand that the "high level class" would be the provider and the "low level class" would be the UI. And that "details" in this case would be the UI class.

Would it be better to use abstractions and pass the provider through the constructor?

*Clarification: I'm not asking for personal opinions (otherwise the question would be closed), I'm asking about applying SOLID principles to Flutter.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention before your application should be based on `abstraction` instead of real implementations. Your current approach describes how to make it wrong in terms of this principle.

To make it right your `UIClass` should depend on the `abstraction class` (because `dart` doesn't have `interfaces`) instead of the real class.
First, create an abstraction

```
class MyProvider implements ChangeNotifier {
  void method();
}
```

Than implementations

```
class MyNetworkProvider extends ChangeNotifier implements MyProvider {
  @override
  void method() {...}
}

class MyDatabaseProvider extends ChangeNotifier implements MyProvider {
  @override
  void method() {...}
}
```

Initialise your provider with **one** of implementation

```
runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
  create: (_) => MyNetworkProvider(),
  child: ...
));
```

And make dependency on the abstraction

```
class UIClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     MyProvider myProvider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);
     //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't fully undestanded. You haven't reduce the coupling, haven't you? If you want to change the provider you still have to modify the UI Class. Maybe should I pass MyNetworkProvider as an argument in the constructor with MyProvider's type?

Comment: The thing is that you have 1 abstraction but **n** implementations can be. For example, you have **MyNetworkProvider** and **MyDatabaseProvider** but your **UIClass** doesn't know what exactly implementation it operates because it knows only about  **MyProvider** abstraction and if after you will replace an current implementation with a new one then the rest app will continue working without any change.

Comment: Ok, I start to understand. Could you add how would you declare the provider? (I mean when you declare the `ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) =>...)`). And, how the UIClass knows which one (MyNetworkProvider or MyDatabaseProvider) use?